# ViewPager as Facebook/Instagram app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to make an app with the same beahavior as Facebook and Instagram app. I mean, I would like to make 4 independent tabs, which each one can load fragments, update action bar (but keep the loaded fragment) and update the content with an actionbar button in the Activity.

What I have:
I have 4 tabs loading fragments and with a OffScreen limited to keep the content loaded, but the problema is because I don't have access to the loaded fragment from the activity (which I could update the actionbar title and update just the content of that fragment). I've looked for some solutions, but it didn't work because they just could retrieve the root fragment, not the loaded fragment (after user navigates inside that fragment and load another ones).

I would like a behavior as the facebook. It keeps the state of the fragment of each tab and also can refresh just one fragment and they also update actionbar title.

Comment: I am also looking for same but meanwhile as you want access of loaded fragment from activity look for  SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter.java on this page https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: I've found a solution! After looking for it in some places and trying to make a good interactive tab app, I've made my own code and now I share with you: [Here is the code on GitHub. Feel Free to comment or suggest some changes =)](https://github.com/renanbandeira/interactiveViewPager)